# <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, compiler-errors, file-not-found

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps into my xcode project.
I strictly followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project). Unfortunately I get an error:

```
error: 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
```

I changed from <> to "", now it finds GoogleMaps.h!

However, I get the same error over the other 35 headers included in the SDK. I can't edit each one of them, I also don't want to as that would take lots of time + that's probably the wrong way to do that.

I'm not really experienced with xcode, but I found some topics on the internet, none of which actually helped me.

What am I doing wrong here?

Waiting for an answer,
Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Search Navigator (CMD+3) select replace on the left an hit "replace all"

[image]

Comment: I played with the Header Search path settings and I somehow got it to "work". now I get another error [too long to be posted here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NBMrz0Qk)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 # import "GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h"
```